# If $u_n$ (sequence of harmonic functions) converges weakly to $u$ in $L^2(\Omega)$, then $\Delta u = 0$ in $\Omega$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> If a sequence of harmonic functions $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ (converges weakly) in $L^2(\Omega)$, then $\Delta u = 0$ in $\Omega$.

Recall a sequence of functions $f_n$ defined on an open set $\Omega$ is said to converge weakly in $L^2(\Omega)$ to a function $f$ if:
$$\int f_n(x)\,g(x)\,dx \to \int f(x)\,g(x)\,dx \hspace{1cm} \forall g \in L^2 (\Omega).$$

My first thought is just to pass the limit using the Mean Value Theorem since if MVT holds that implies $u$ is harmonic. However, I don't think that works with 'weak convergence' with my definition above.

Comment: For $y\in \Omega$, consider the characteristic functions of balls and of spherical shells with centre $y$.

Comment: Hello! I’ve made a slight edit to the MathJax in your post: I’ve introduced a small space `\,` between the functions of more than one character and before the differentials, as recommended in the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5057/347062). If you find this too pedantic, feel free to roll it back! $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$u_n \rightharpoonup u\implies \int_\Omega u_n(x)\phi(x)dx \to \int_\Omega u(x)\phi(x)dx \hspace{1cm} \forall \phi \in C^\infty_0 (\Omega).$$

in particular $$ \phi \in C^\infty_0  \implies \Delta \phi \in C^\infty_0 $$

Hence 
$$\int_\Omega u_n(x)\Delta\phi(x)dx \to \int_\Omega u(x)\Delta\phi(x)dx\Longleftrightarrow \int_\Omega (u_n(x)-u(x))\Delta\phi(x)dx \to 0\hspace{1cm} \forall \phi \in C^\infty_0 (\Omega).$$
But using [integration by part](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwjJ2rTB5d7WAhXBNpoKHTMJBbsQFghCMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmath.okstate.edu%2Fpeople%2Fbinegar%2F5233-S96%2F5233-l21.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3qMVvq5B_whfPlbjjjNJGT) or By derivative in [the sense of distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics))
we know that 
$$\int_\Omega (u_n(x)-u(x))\Delta\phi(x)dx =\int_\Omega \Delta(u_n(x)-u(x))\phi(x)dx~~\\ =\int_\Omega -\Delta u(x)\phi(x)dx ~~\to 0~~~\forall~~ \phi \in C^\infty_0 (\Omega).$$ Since
$$\Delta u_n =0$$

Hence, 
$$\int_\Omega -\Delta u(x)\phi(x)dx =0~~\forall~~ \phi \in C^\infty_0 (\Omega)\Longleftrightarrow \Delta u = 0~~\text{a.e on }~~\Omega$$

Answer (score 1):

It uses the Wely's Lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_lemma_(Laplace_equation) as follows:

> If $u\in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ satisfies $\int_\Omega u \Delta \varphi dx=0$ for all $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$, then $u$ is smooth (possibly after redefining on a set of zero measure) and harmonic.

It suffices to show that $\int_\Omega u \Delta \varphi =0$. For any $\varphi$, we have 
$$
\int_\Omega u_n\Delta \varphi dx=0,
$$
by integration and the property that $u_n$ is harmonic. Then by limiting above and using the weak convergence, we have 
$$
\int_\Omega u \Delta \varphi dx= \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_\Omega u_n\Delta \varphi dx=0.
$$
For the proof of Wely's Lemma, please see:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the difference between the $L^2$ space and $C^\infty$ space matter here though?

Comment: @Dragonite You need redefine the function at  a null measure set